# What is the term for a game where only the players roll the dice?

Tags: terminology, semi-diceless

We've got questions about [who should roll the dice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12491/4398) and [how](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1193/4398) or [why](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4108/4398) a GM might give up rolling the dice. What is it called when that happens, though?

[Some people](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1193/4398) use [semi-diceless](/questions/tagged/semi-diceless) to mean "only the players roll the dice," but [the tag's info page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/semi-diceless/info) has a much broader definition, so I'm thinking if I used that phrase it'd cause confusion.

**Is there a term to describe systems (like Apocalypse World, Great Ork Gods, Lady Blackbird, and Lasers & Feelings) that have a GM, but only the players roll dice?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Such systems are called "player-facing"

I don't know how ubiquitous this terminology is, but it certainly exists. I first came upon it in tremulus (p. 4):

> All rolls of the dice are “player-facing,” meaning that all the rolls in the game are done exclusively by the players.

A quick search reveals the term being used in [blogposts](http://ronblessing.blogspot.com.au/2010/01/player-facing-rolls.html) and [forum discussions](https://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-774892.html).
Here's a slightly expanded definition from [one such post](http://www.rpgalchemy.com/player-facing-mechanics/):

> Of all the innovations in roleplaying over the years my favorite is the concept of “player-facing” mechanics. For those unfamiliar with the term, player-facing refers to game elements that require the player to roll dice, react, or make decisions instead of the gamemaster. Most every game out there features a majority of player-facing elements such as attack rolls, skill checks, or saving throws along with several gamemaster-facing elements such as NPC attack rolls and damage rolls.

As the term may not be well-known, perhaps describing such games as having **"player-facing rolls"** would be better.

Comment: +1 ... "Player Facing" is the most used term I've seen for it.  Most of the games I've seen do so don't have a term for it, but just do it.

Answer (score 4):

[Legendary lives](http://www.hauntedattic.org/legendarylives.html) uses the term '**semi-diceless**' for this style of gaming (emphasis mine):

> **The  use  of  dice  by  the  players  and  not  the referee  is 
>   called  semi-diceless  role  playing**,  and *Legendary  Lives* is  the 
>   first  game  to  employ  this method.  This  innovative  system  takes
>   many traditional  pressures  off  the  participants.  It  frees the
>   referee and the players to concentrate on what they enjoy most. The
>   referee focuses on running the adventure while the players concentrate
>   on running their characters. Both receive the maximum amount of
>   pleasure from the freedom *Legendary Lives* gives them.

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether *Legendary Lives* really was the first game to employ this method. It's certainly pretty old, and was where I originally got the idea from before employing it in *Great Ork Gods*.

As you say, it may be misunderstood, but so - I think - will 'player facing' and semi-diceless certainly has a long pedigree.